# What is causing a type error when trying to modify Mathematica state from a function linked with LibraryLink

Tags: librarylink

I've managed to reduce my problem to a very simple C program:

```
#include "mathlink.h"
#include "WolframLibrary.h"

int SetX( WolframLibraryData libData )
{
    int errorCode;
    int nextPacket;
    MLINK link = libData->getMathLink( libData );
    MLPutFunction( link, "EvaluatePacket", 1 );
    MLPutFunction( link, "Set", 2 );
    MLPutSymbol( link, "x" );
    MLPutDouble( link, 3.14159 );
    errorCode = libData->processMathLink( link );
    if ( errorCode != 0 )
        return errorCode;
    nextPacket = MLNextPacket( link );
    if ( nextPacket == RETURNPKT )
        MLNewPacket( link );
    return 0;
}

DLLEXPORT int WolframLibrary_getVersion()
{
    return WolframLibraryVersion;
}

DLLEXPORT int WolframLibrary_initialize(WolframLibraryData libData)
{
    return 0;
}

DLLEXPORT int testIt(WolframLibraryData libData, mint argc, MArgument*
                     margs, MArgument result)
{
    int error = SetX( libData );
    if ( error != 0 ) {
        libData->Message( "error setting x" );
    }
    return error;
}
```

I use `AppendTo` to add the directory containing the compiled
shared object/Dll to `$LibraryPath`, then do:

```
In[4]:= LibraryFunctionLoad[ "CB", "testIt", {}, Void ]
Out[4]= LibraryFunction[ <>, testIt, {}, {}]

In[5]:= %[]
During evaluation of In[5]:= LibraryFunction::error setting x: -- Message text not found -- >>
During evaluation of In[5]:= LibraryFunction::typerr: An error caused by inconsistent types was encountered evaluating the function testIt. >>
Out[5]= LibraryFunctionError[LIBRARY_TYPE_ERROR,1]
```

Regretfully, the error message doesn't tell me what type is
wrong, and what type I should be using instead.  (I've tried
using `MLPutString`, insteamd of `MLPutSymbol`, in the above,
with the same results.)

I've tried this with the same results under Windows and Linux,
so I don't think it's a problem with the build procedure I'm
using; but FWIW, here is the command line used to build the
shared object under Linux:

```
Gabi (41): echo $MATHINCL
    -I /usr/local/Wolfram/Mathematica/8.0/SystemFiles/IncludeFiles/C -I /usr/local/Wolfram/Mathematica/8.0/SystemFiles/Links/MathLink/DeveloperKit/Linux-x86-64/CompilerAdditions
    Gabi (42): echo $MATHLIB
/usr/local/Wolfram/Mathematica/8.0/SystemFiles/Links/MathLink/DeveloperKit/Linux-x86-64/CompilerAdditions/libML64i3.so
Gabi (43): gcc -shared -fPIC $MATHINCL CB.c $MATHLIB -o CB.so
```

(I use something similar from CygWin bash under Windows, with
options /MDd and /Tc.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looking into this, I can see that the docs are simply wrong. The `processMathLink()` function returns TRUE on success, FALSE otherwise, not what the docs describe. We'll make sure this gets fixed. Your program looks to be correct in all other ways.

Comment: Thanks.  Not only does my small test work now, but I was able to get the actual code working.  In the actual code, I had another small error: I'd spelled the first function `"EvalutatePacket"`.  Is there anyway to get better error detection---as far as I can see, the spelling error only made the packet a no-op.  (Maybe by processing the response packet?  In the actual code, I know that the head of what I'm setting should be a `LibraryFunction`; just checking for that would probably suffice.)